# Install Eclipse-cpp-juno in Raspberry Pi 3 B+

Tags: eclipse, c++

I managed to unzip eclipse-cpp-juno-SR2-linux-gtk-x86_64.tar.gz in Raspberry Pi 3 B+ board.

However, I got difficulty to install thereafter.

Please help. Thanks!

Comment: You grabbed a x86_64 (for intel/amd x86_64 architecture) intended file, since you are on a pi (arm architecture) you should have grabbed a version intended to be run on your hardware (not a different architecture).  You also didn't tell us what OS you are running (including release)

Comment: My bad, sorry. I am using Raspbian OS for PI3 board.

Comment: Possible off-topic question. This site only supports Ubuntu and official flavors; raspbian is neither sorry.  Your question would be appropriate on http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com or https://unix.stackexchange.com.  The file you mentioned is a tarball (the last part of the name tells you this and that is uses gzip compression)  It needs to be expanded and you follow the steps of the README or install instructions. You may have trouble with it (ie. need steps not documented in readme) as you grabbed the wrong architecture [ie. version for a different cpu family].

Comment: Also note that Eclipse Juno is **7** years old and won't run on recent versions of Java.